# Let me see stars

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-stars

Here is how the chat sidebar looks, annotated with how interesting/useful stuff is:

[image]

On my monitor, I can usually only see the top two or three starred items, but I want to see more. Could something be added so that I could:

- Reorder chat sidebar items?
- Collapse chat sidebar items?
- Scroll the sidebar so I can see more stars?

Comment: Now ***this***, is a fine example of what every meta-post should look like.

Comment: @Mysticial It's taken years to refine my craft

Comment: All your up votes are belong to you

Comment: Related: [Adapt the chat sidebar for displays with limited height](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158041/adapt-the-chat-sidebar-for-displays-with-limited-height). And the problem is much worse on my tablet, I can see at most the first room I'm in, and never any starred messages.

Comment: You forgot another option: "Get a wider screen" ;)

Comment: @ThiefMaster *Width* is not an issue.

Comment: https://github.com/rlemon/UserScripts/tree/master/StackExchange/Upbar "kinda working maybe not really" userscript to free up some space by moving the users list to a auto-hide-able top bar. Could be useful?

Comment: I prefer [a hardware solution](http://images.pcworld.com/images/article/2012/06/portrait20mode20monitor-11378139.jpg) for this problem.

Comment: @PopularDemand Laptop

Comment: Optimal solution: Get a taller screen.

Answer (score 46):

I vote for **collapsing items**. All of them.

I think that having scrollable things will just make it feel more messy. Just a  User Experience thing. Collapsing feels more "organized" and you can choose what you want to see without having to scroll; just *click* et voilà.

On a lower priority, the "other rooms you're in" list could use some improvement; for example, removing the "last message" preview. If there's a new message, we could have a **+1**, **+2**, etc., somewhere on the side, so the list gets shorter.

By the way, that's the longest room description I've seen until now.

Comment: Collapsing would be ideal, and work well with tablets. I never need the room description to be there, and the list of users is only occasionally useful.

Comment: Even collapsed, in the example shown above, you would only be able to see at most 7 starred posts *collapsed*. Moreover, you would really only be able to view 1  or 2 open at the same time (depending on which were collapsed). In other words, if you were to want to review all 8 hidden, you still couldn't. And to review just a few of them would require 2 clicks, per item, to expand and then collapse. By the 3rd one examined, the next ones would start to get truncated. This doesn't seem very user friendly to me.

Comment: @TravisJ Well, 7 is still a lot better than 2.  But I agree, there are probably better solutions (I just upvoted your bookmarklet solution).

Comment: @jadarnel27 - 7 collapsed ones though (as in only 1 line of text - or whatever the collapsed version is). If it were 7 full fledged ones then I would think that would be pretty decent. But there is nothing like wondering what the next part `<cutoff>`. Basically it would require 2 clicks for each of those items to deal with. Personally that seems tedious. And if you expanded the 7th item, the rest would still be hidden. The 6th would only show 2 lines and hide the rest. The 5th would.. well you get the point :).

Answer (score 28):

Please oh please make the user list collapsible to one line. It takes up far too much real estate on popular rooms.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4549488 your wish is my command (there could be so much more done to this script... I got it started for you all :P)

Comment: well, I can't fault you for trying, but that is one ugly hack right there :P Still, it is a good start.

Answer (score 10):

I got you guys covered :) This bothered me for a really, really, long time. So, I recently decided to write a surprisingly simple script for it that I use as a bookmarklet. Bookmarklets code can be saved as a bookmark and ran while at the current page, or it can be ran by entering it in the url as

```
url input field [javascript:pastecodehere();             ]
```

Here is the script:

```
javascript:(function(){var $s = $("#starred-posts");var h =$s.height(); $s.css({height:h+"px",overflow:"auto"});})()
```

Pretty simple right? It creates a scroll bar for the starred area as seen below (Note that this even works if you expand the "Show More Stars" link without rerunning the script).

### Before

[image: before]

### After

[image: after]

Answer (score 6):

HodofHod wrote a [userscript](https://github.com/HodofHod/SE-Modifications/raw/master/ChatMods.user.js), linked from [here](https://github.com/HodofHod/SE-Modifications/blob/master/Installing.md), to add scrolling to the right panel to be able to see more stars.  I've been using it for months and would never go back to the old, limited way.

Answer (score 5):

While this would be a nice inherent feature, in the mean time you can use the [**More Stars** script](https://stackapps.com/questions/3260/more-stars-userscript-that-frees-up-room-so-you-can-see-more-starred-messages) by Sterno.