# Allow canceling stars from message or Starred Tab in room info

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-stars

Firstly,

I have already looked into [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166376/208463) feature request. But its still not implemented.

Problem:

We, as a room owner, are responsible to cancel a few stars which are not quite meaningful. See the below screenshot. There are some messages which were not worth starring. (I have highlighted those stars with a red mark.)

[image]

Now I am not able to cancel the stars as these stars don't come up in the right side starred section of room due to new messages got starred.

Feature request:

*Either*

Room owner and moderator should be able to cancel stars from message itself

*Or*

Room owner and moderator should be able to cancel stars from starred section in room info.

I think second option is good to be considered.

Edit: I am nominating the question to be reopened, as the old question does not contain any answer. And the feature is must.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I mentioned in my question, that I have already looked into that question. But its not implemented. Please check. There isn't answer there :/

Comment: Still, when there's an existing feature request we can bump it (edit, bounty) rather then starting new same feature request.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ok. I suggested an edit on that post. Thanks. I will delete this question :)