# How to remove pin from a deleted message?

Tags: support, chat, chat-pins

I recently came across a pinned message in a room for which I am a Room Owner ([General discussion for Hinduism Stack Exchange](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/15189/hinduism)). The message was posted by a moderator and pinned. This was later deleted by a moderator. Message is gone but the pin is still there. The message just shows removed and no option to unpin or cancel stars. This message is not shown in the starboard also.

[image: Deleted message with a pin]

I couldn't either add or remove stars. How to remove this message which shows with a pin? Is this a bug?

Comment: Use a userscript I wrote: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270121/158100

Comment: @rene removing stars and unpin are different actions. (Your script can work with a small tweak of course, but non programmer will find it hard to do on their own. :))

Comment: "This message is not shown in the starboard also." Then why to another.

Comment: @Pandya because in slow pace rooms, it can stay for long days?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am not finding it at right panel. What's "slow pace rooms"?

Comment: @Pandya rooms with one or two messages per day for example. So the removed message with the pin will appear for everyone for long time.

Comment: "Then why to another" What do you mean @Pandya ?

Comment: @NogShine Oh! I didn't notice spelling correction. I meant "Why to bother?"

Comment: @Pandya Just curious about it. I wanted to know how to remove it. "Curiosity killed the cat" they say.

Answer (score 3):

As room owner, you can get the message ID via its history, then you can run such a JS code in the browser's developer tools console:

```
$.post("https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/messages/7475694/owner-star", {"fkey": $("#fkey").val()});
```

Replace the domain with proper chat domain, and the number with the proper chat message ID.